# Python optimization - Server response time is bad

Tags: python, performance

I have a Python server app running via PyPy that uses select.epoll to monitor clients for incoming data.

When data is ready, I loop through clients recving all of it, breaking it into lines (if necessary), and processing.

If the line is "~" I simply call sock.send("~\n") which the client interprets as a ping response.

The problem is that pings are oddly very high and oddly highly variable, ranging from 90ms to about 3000ms with 300-1000ms being the average, in my personal experience. Pinging continually yields results that are jumping all over the place. (My "real" ping to the server is about 85ms.)

I used cProfile to check if there was anything slowing things down and here are the results I got:

```
Thu Aug 15 04:05:56 2013    profile.out

     17401043 function calls (17399987 primitive calls) in 815.728 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time
List reduced from 960 to 25 due to restriction <25>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000  815.728  815.728 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000  815.728  815.728 /root/app/src/serv/appserver/main.py:28(main)
    1    0.302    0.302  814.608  814.608 /root/app/src/serv/appserver/server.py:214(main_loop)
 2457  806.185    0.328  806.185    0.328 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}
 2067    0.070    0.000    6.069    0.003 /root/app/src/serv/appserver/client.py:89(read)
 2274    0.013    0.000    5.875    0.003 /root/app/src/serv/appserver/client.py:150(handle_read_line)
 2264    0.062    0.000    5.600    0.002 /root/app/src/serv/appserver/client.py:164(handle_client_line)
```

I'm not experienced with profiling Python, but it looks to me like 806 out of 815 seconds of runtime was spent polling, so high response times are not due to being overloaded or wasting time elsewhere.

What else could be causing my response times to be so high?

Socket init code:

```
self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.server_socket.bind(bind)
self.server_socket.listen(5)
self.server_socket.setblocking(0)
```

Edit:
I've set TCP_NODELAY socket option. Results are noticeably better now but still quite bad. Still jumping around from 90ms to 500ms to 1000ms.

Comment: Perhapse show us the epoll code as well, considering that's where it looks like it's haging.

Comment: No, the *total time* was spent polling. Because a async server sits idle most of the time waiting for a connection. That is *entirely normal*. There is no point in profiling `select.epoll` because that code is almost entirely handled by the OS, and is highly optimized in any case.

Comment: Maybe it's worth trying ab (ApacheBench)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench

Comment: Can you extract and show us some minimal example code?

Comment: Also: do you see the variability and/or the high times with CPython instead of PyPy?

Comment: Hi Armin, CPython seems almost as bad as PyPy (maybe slightly better) so I don't think it's a PyPy issue. Thanks